# Java returning null pointer exception for SQL query that gets passed to JSP

Tags: java, mysql, jsp

I am working on a school assignment that required us to use SQL statements in Java code as well as use the `LIKE` operator for a search. In order to properly search I have to get a string from the user, and split the string by any delimiter, and then run the query like so:

`SELECT * FROM movies WHERE (movies.title LIKE '%userInput%');`

I then return this query in the form  of an ArrayList.

Now, when I was testing it out. I originally tested it with no user input, and my query became: `SELECT * FROM movies WHERE (movies.title LIKE '%%');`. This gave me the correct results.

However when I put a `title` in there, all of the sudden I get a `NullPointerException` on this line:

`if(title.equals("")) { return "(movies.title LIKE '%%') ";` from this section of my code:

```
public String getSearchString(String title) {
    if(title.equals("")) { return "(movies.title LIKE '%%') "; }
    String ret = "(";
    ArrayList<String> titleArray = Util.splitSearch(title);
    for(int i = 0; i < titleArray.size() - 1; ++i) {
        String temp = titleArray.get(i);
        String stmt = "movies.title LIKE '%" + temp + "%' OR ";
        ret += stmt;
    }
    String temp = "movies.title LIKE '%" + titleArray.get(titleArray.size() - 1) + "%')";
    ret += temp;
    return ret;
}
```

This is then called like so:

```
public List<Movie> listMovies(String title) throws SQLException {
    List<Movie> search = new ArrayList<Movie>();
    if(null != title && title.isEmpty()) { title = ""; }
    ResultSet res = queryMovies(getSearchString(title));
    while(res.next()) {
        Movie mov = new Movie();
        mov.setTitle(res.getString("title"));
        search.add(mov);
    }
    return search;
}

private static queryMovies(String st) throws SQLException {
    ResultSet res = null;
    try {
        PreparedStatement ps = dbcon.prepareStatement(st);
        res = ps.executeQuery();
    } catch(SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return res;
}
```

I unfortunately have to do this since I won't know how much a user will enter. And I am also not allowed to use external libraries that make the formatting easier. For reference my `Util.splitSearch(...)` method looks like this. It should be retrieving anything that is a alphanumeric character and should be splitting on anything that is not alphanumeric:

```
public static ArrayList<String> splitSearch(String str) {
    String[] strArray = str.split("[^a-zA-Z0-9']");
    return new ArrayList(Arrays.asList(strArray));
}
```

What is interesting is when I pass in `getSearchString("");` explicitly, I do not get a `NullPointerException`. It is only when I allows the variable `title` to be used do I get one. And I still get one when no string is entered.

Am I splitting the String wrong? Am I somehow giving SQL the wrong statement? Any help would be appreciated, as I am very new to this.

Answer (score 0):

the "title" which is passed from input is null, hence you're getting nullpointerexception when you do title.equals("").

Best practices suggest you do a null check like (null != title && title.equals("")). 
You can also do "".equals(title)

Comment: I just realized this myself. However, After changing the code to say `if(title.isEmpty() || title == null || title.equals("")) { title = ""; }` the problem still persists..

Comment: even now you're performing an operation before the null check, hence nullpointerexception, it should be `if (null != title && title.isEmpty()) { title = "";}`

Comment: Changing it to what you said, and then checking to see later if title.equals("") returns a `NullPointerException`. Any idea why?

Comment: But I'm not doing `null.something` anymore? I thought? Unless checking to see if `title.equals("")` counts?

Comment: @Alex: In your code, is it `||` or `&&` operator? `||` will not short circuit and will evaluate next expression if first expression is `false`